# Return multiple corresponding value based on a cell in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a dashboard in Excel and trying to return only certain values from another worksheets based on particular cell. I tried this in vlookup but returns only the first match. Can VBA be used for this? See attached picture for details.

[image]

Comment: Advanced Filter will let you extract data from a table based on criteria. It will do exactly what the image implies. You will want to use the "copy to another location" functionality. The data, criteria and results can all be in different places.